# How to add django variable name inside a href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, django, variables

I need to add dynamic images to a page but it doesn’t work. I'm getting an error:
[image]

```
<img src="{% static 'geonode/img/layers/{{layer.title}}.png' %}"
                                                 class="add-layer-img d-block"/>
```

```
<span class="base-layer-title d-block">{{layer.title}}</span>
```

but the title works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `{{layer.title}}` after `{% static %}`

```
<img src="{% static 'geonode/img/layers/' %}{{layer.title}}.png"
                                                 class="add-layer-img d-block"/>
```